# How to let Eclipse run different make targets before Run/Debug

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am developing a C++ app in Eclipse with CDT plugin, using my own Makefile. Is there a way how to force Eclipse to run `make all` before I **run** the project but `make debug` before I try to **debug** it? I want to have the app compiled with `-g` switch during debugging but with `-O3` when I run it, without manually rewriting the `-g` switch in the Makefile each time.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have created a C++ project of type 'Makefile Project' (i.e where the user is supposed to provide his own Makefile), then you will be able to create several 'Build configurations' using the menu :

```
Project > Build Configurations > Manage ...
```

I suggest you create a 'Debug' configuration where the build settings will be 'make debug'
and a 'Release' or 'Default' configuration where the build settings are 'make all'.
This way you will be able to build and run/debug in either mode after selecting the wished configuration in menu :

```
Project > Build Configurations > Set active > ...
```

I hope this can help!
Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I can only wish the Build Configuration could be not shared between Debug/Run configuration (I would prefer setting Debug for debugging and Release for running, but the Use Active option must suffice).